# Is there a way I can print multiple lines using one print()?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and having trouble understanding Python. I would like to use only one `print()` to lessen its usage.

```py
first_name = "Gabh"
Gabh ="Musician"
age = 21
height = 5.4
weight = 47
print(first_name + (" is a"), Gabh)
print(("age:"), age)
print(("height:"), height)
print(("weight:"), weight)
```

With this code, this is what I'm getting:

```py
Gabh is a Musician
age: 21
height: 5.4
weight: 47
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to have a preconfigured multiline block of text to print, and just add some values to it (bit like doing a mail-merge in Word), you can use the `str.format` method.

```
>>> help(str.format)

format(...)
 |      S.format(*args, **kwargs) -> str
 |
 |      Return a formatted version of S, using substitutions from args and kwargs.
 |      The substitutions are identified by braces ('{' and '}').
```

Multiline strings have `"""` (or, less commonly, `'''`).

```py
template = """{name} is a {role}.
Age: {age} 
Height: {height} metres
Weight: {weight} milligrams"""

gabh = template.format(
    name="Gabh",
    role="Musician",
    age=21,
    height=5.4,
    weight=47
)

print(gabh)
```

(This is slightly different to f-strings, where values get put into the string at the moment it's created.)

If you have a dictionary with keys matching the `{stuff} in {curly braces}` in your template string, you can use `format_map`:

```py
template = """{name} is a {role}.
Age: {age} 
Height: {height} metres
Weight: {weight} milligrams"""

gabh = {
    "name": "Gabh",
    "role": "Musician",
    "age": 21,
    "height": 5.4,
    "weight": 47,
}

print(template.format_map(gabh))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a single `print()` statement, with all the items separated by commas.

```
print(first_name, "is a", Gabh, "age:", age, "height:", height, "weight:", weight)
```

Comment: To add to John's answer, you can insert line breaks with a special string: "\n". This would help obtain your 4 row print statment instead of having 1 massive row.

Comment: Thanks  :D I added "\n" to keep them in same format in the output.

Comment: @alexpdev The question was edited after I answered to add "multiple lines" in the title.  Before that, it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to use the '\n' command in the string. You might also want to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to make your code cleaner :)

```
print(first_name + (" is a"), Gabh, '\n', "age:", age, '\n',"height:", height, "\n","weight:",weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a nice clean way of writing everything with one print statement. Note specifically that `print()` has a possible `sep` argument that we can set to be a line break `\n`.

```
print(f'{first_name} is a {Gabh}', f'age: {age}', f'height: {height}', f'weight: {weight}', sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Gabh is a Musician
age: 21
height: 5.4
weight: 47
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_name = "Gabh"
Gabh = "Musician"
age = 21
height = 5.4
weight = 47

print(f'{first_name} is a {Gabh}\nage: {age}\nheight: {height}\nweight: {weight}')
```